# how to write junit test case for aggregation in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, aggregation

I have aggregation method in service like following:

```java
public List<Demo> demo() {
            Aggregation aggre = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.project("date").and(month("$date")).as("month"),
                Aggregation.group("$month").count().as("count"),
                project("count").and("month").previousOperation(),
                Aggregation.match(where("month").is(2)));

        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggre, "demo", Demo.class).getMappedResults();
}
```

How can I write a JUnit test case for the above method in spring boot?

I have tried using the following:

```java
    @Test
    public void demoTest(){

       List<Demo> items= demoService.demo();
        Assert.assertEquals(1, items.size());
    }
```

I have tried the above code but it throws a `NullPointerException`. How can I solve this?

Comment: People will need to know what `demoService` is in your test, and any preparation you're doing on it which makes you think it has 1 demo in there.  But I expect someone will point you to the 'what is a NullPointerException and how do I fix it' answer first, so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510#218510

Comment: I really don't know how can i solve this

Comment: Tell us which line is throwing the exception, as well as the setup details I mentioned in the other comment.

Comment: List<Demo> items= demoService.demo();
this line shows NullPointerException. i have done aggregation of count number of items by month.

Comment: Which is also why I asked for 'what `demoService` is in your test'.  How are you initialising it?  Is `demoService` `null` at the point you're calling it?  Are you passing it a `null` `mongoTemplate` when you create one, etc.

Comment: But the answer I linked above goes into _great_ detail about what a `NullPointerException` is and how to find the cause of it.